# fasterxml jackson ObjectMapping set @JsonView class not working

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, fasterxml

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter objConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.NONE);
objMapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(View.class);
objConverter.setObjectMapper(objMapper);
objConverter.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView(View.class);
```

after

```
objMapper.getSerializationConfig()
```

has different reference than `SerializationConfig` created with method `(..).withView(..)`

It look as if new `SerializationConfig` is not applied to `objMapper`

Hot to solve this issue? Also my @JsonView annotations are not working.

fasterxml.jackson 2.3.0

Comment: Leave out tabs from formatting, that doesn't work well here. Also backquote inline code to increase visual recognition of code. Readability increases the chance of someone understanding your problem, and thus of an answer.

Comment: Maybe this question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21054896/4576054

Answer (score 0):

Based on the linked answer by [Javier Molla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4576054/javier-moll%C3%A1):

You should use `.configure()` on your ObjectMapper and preferably reuse the mapper.

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, false);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

You can put the serialization features in a static block and reuse the mapper => performance boost.